# Telnet command missing on Windows 2008 R2 machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, telnet

I have a Windows 2008 R2 machine that is being used for development machine.

When I try to use Telnet I get the error:

> Telnet is not recognised as an internal or external command ...

I have done a search on the disk it is not there.

Is there something that I need to turn on to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that Telnet is not installed by default on Server 2008 machines. (Or Windows 7 for that matter). To resolve you will need to open up Server Manager and enable Telnet Client as a feature.

If you need any more help please let me know.